# How to generate all arrangements of two values in 5 columns using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have two values: **1** and **0**. And I have **5** columns. I need to generate all possible arrangements in Excel.

---

For example, I have **2** columns and 2 values: **0** , **1**. There are only **4** possible arrangements (with repetitions):

```
1 | 0
0 | 1
0 | 0
1 | 1
```

---

I need to generate all posible arrangements of **1** and **0** for **5** columns. Number of possible arrangements with repetition is defined by formula: **n^k**. 
So, for **5** columns and **2** values it is 2^5 = **32** arrangements.

In Excel:

[image]

and so on

---

Is it possible to automate it without typing ones and zeros manually?

Comment: Well, what you have is 32 rows of BITS for a 5 BITS number, right? I would simple insert a column at the left (or any other place) that will contain a running number from 0 to 31. Then, at the leftmost column would define a formula that extracts the leftmost BIT of a 5 bits number (something like divide the number by 16 and take the MOD 2 of the result). The same for the next column, and the next, and so forth. Then, select the entire row and drag (copy) the formulae to the remaining rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to count from 0 to 31 in binary and then split the binary result out over the columns. You can do it like this:

[image]

- Column A - just the number i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
- Column B - `=DEC2BIN(A2,5)`
- Columns C to G - `=MID($B2,C$1,1)` and then drag down and across

For example - for the formula to get the binary digit in the correct column:

[image]